# usage of @ViewChild annotation returns undefined in my code

Tags: angular, angular5

I have an angular 2 UI . I have defined a text area in my component template and i am try to get a reference to that text area with @ViewChild annotation . However it is returning undefined . i know the reason but no idea how i can fix this issue. The problem is in the

so this is my text area in the component html

```
<textarea id="messageTxt" formControlName="message" rows="6" [placeholder]="'PLACEHOLDERS.MESSAGE' | translate" #messageTxt></textarea>
```

so i am pasting part of the code from my component ts file as below. 
messageTextArea turns out to be undefined. I guess this is because of the ngOnInit method we are waiting the form to be created until we get a response from the service . any idea how can i rewrite the code so that I can get a proper reference in the messageTextArea variable.

```
export class SmsTemplateFormComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('messageTxt') messageTextArea: ElementRef;

constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private templatesService: TemplatesService,
    private configService: ConfigService,
    private accountService: AccountsService
  ) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.messageTextArea.nativeElement,'keyup').pipe(
      map( (e: KeyboardEvent) => (e.target as HTMLTextAreaElement).value),
      debounceTime(10),  
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap( (value) =>  this.templatesService.retrieveSmsSegmentCount(value)  )
     ).subscribe(
        response => {
          this.segmentCount = response.segmentCount;
        } 
     );
  }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.isFormLoading = true;
    this.accountService.get(this.account.id).subscribe(
        (value) => {
            this.account = value;
            this.isFormLoading = false;
            this.messagePrefix = value.messagePrefix;
            this.formGroup = this.fb.group(
                  {
                    defaultTemplate: [this.defaultInitialValue],
                    language: [null, Validators.required],
                    message: [ this.messagePrefix ? this.messagePrefix:'', [Validators.required]],
                    longUrl: ['']
                  },
                  {
                    validator: [
                                hasUrlTagValidator(TemplatesService.urlTag), 
                                messagePrefixSMSValidator(this.messagePrefix? this.messagePrefix: null, 'message')
                              ]
                  }
                );

              combineLatest(
                this.messageControl.valueChanges,
                this.urlControl.valueChanges
              ).subscribe(([message, url]) => {
                const { html, length } = this.templatesService.compileSmsTemplate(
                  message,
                  url ? this.placeholderUrl : ''
                );

                this.messageHtml = html;
                this.messageLength = length;
              });

              if (this.template) {
                this.formGroup.setValue({
                  defaultTemplate: this.template.defaultTemplate,
                  language: this.template.language,
                  message: this.template.text,
                  longUrl: this.template.longUrl
                });
              }

              this.urlControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
                const messageValue: string = this.messageControl.value;
                if (!messageValue || !messageValue.includes(TemplatesService.urlTag)) {
                  this.messageControl.setValue(messageValue + TemplatesService.urlTag);
                }
              });

              this.templatesService.retrieveSmsSegmentCount(this.messageControl.value)
              .subscribe( response => {
                this.segmentCount = response.segmentCount;
                });
        }
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need `fromEvent` in your case. You can just bind the `keyup` event to your textarea:

```
<textarea id="messageTxt" formControlName="message" rows="6" [placeholder]="'PLACEHOLDERS.MESSAGE' | translate" (keyup)="doStuff(messageTxt.value)" #messageTxt></textarea>
```

Then in your component:

```
doStuff(value: string) {
  // do whatever with the value
}
```